# How can I create an Incanter series based on a range of values

Tags: clojure, incanter

I've got an Incanter dataset with 3 columns: a date/timestamp, a response time and a message size. What I'd like to do is create a scatter plot with the date/timestamp on the x axis and response times as the y axis.

This is easy enough, but I'd like to generate separate series of data based on the message size column. Incanter's `scatter-plot` function takes a `:group-by` option, but it appears to only handle discrete values. I'd like the series to be generated by applying some function to the message size column. Some function like:

```
(fn [n]
  (cond
    (< n 5000)                    "small"
    (and (>= n 5000) (< n 20000)) "medium"
    (>= n 20000)                  "large"))
```

Is this possible or is there a better way to accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can synthesize a dataset with a new column with the discrete values calculated using your function, something like this....

```
(def dataset1 (dataset 
               [:x :y] 
               (for [x (range 10) y (range 10)] [x y])))
;=> #'user/dataset1

dataset1
[:x :y]
[0 0]
[0 1]
...
[9 8]
[9 9]

(def dataset2 (with-data dataset1 
  (conj-cols $data 
     (dataset [:size] ($map #(cond
                              (< % 3)   "small"
                              (<= 3 % 6) "medium"
                              (< 6 %)   "large") :x)))))
;=> #'user/dataset2

dataset2
[:x :y :size]
[0 0 "small"]
[0 1 "small"]
...
[9 8 "large"]
[9 9 "large"]
```

add then use the `:group-by` on the discrete value you've generated...

```
(with-data dataset2 
   (view 
      (scatter-plot 
       :x 
       :y 
       :group-by :size )))
```

To give something like this:

[image: incanter plot]

A variant which generates the group-by from two columns:

```
 (def dataset3 
  (with-data dataset1  
    (conj-cols 
      $data 
      (dataset [:size] ($map #(let [sum (+ % %2)] 
                               (cond
                                 (< sum 4 )    "small"
                                 (<= 4 sum 12) "medium"
                                 (> 12 sum )   "large")) [:x :y])))))
```

Which plots like this:

[image: sum plot]